# Search Table in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have made one table and am filtering it, but when I clear the search query, the table data doesn't show up, and table gets stuck on the query result.
`SearchBox` is the textbox, `TableData` is the table, and in `Container` I am changing the `SearchBox` and `TableData` states.

Here is my code:

```
var SearchBox = React.createClass({
  doSearch: function() {
    var query = this.refs.searchInput.getDOMNode().value;
    console.log(query)
    this.props.doSearch(query);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        ref="searchInput"
        placeholder="Search Name"
        value={this.props.query}
        onChange={this.doSearch}
      />
    )
  }
})

var TableData = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var rows=[];
    this.props.data.forEach(function(data) {
      rows.push(<tr><td>{data.name}</td><td>{data.roll}</td></tr>)
    });
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Text</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
});

var Container = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  doSearch: function(queryText) {
    //get query result
    var queryResult=[];
    this.state.data.forEach(function(person) {
      console.log("person ",person);
      if (person.name.indexOf(queryText) != -1)
        queryResult.push(person);
      console.log("query result ",queryResult);
    });
    debugger;
    this.setState({
      data: queryResult,
      query:queryText

    })
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data:[],
      query:''
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <SearchBox query = {this.state.query} doSearch={this.doSearch} />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <TableData data = {this.state.data} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <Container url="data2.json"/>,
  document.getElementById('searchApplications')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the initial state, your `doSearch` has not been called, so no filtering has occurred.  When you delete your text value in the search box, `doSearch` is called, which tries to match '' against each person name.  This returns 0 results, resulting in the blank table.  You can fix this by adding a condition to the if statement in `doSearch` checking if `queryText` is blank:

```
doSearch:function(queryText){


  var queryResult=[];
  this.state.data.forEach(function(person){
      console.log("person ",person);
      if(person.name.indexOf(queryText)!=-1 || queryText === '')
        queryResult.push(person);
        console.log("query result ",queryResult);
  });
  debugger;
  this.setState({
      data: queryResult,
      query:queryText
  })
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use the `onChange` event a bit differently and you shouldn't need to use `ref`.  When the `SearchBox` is created, retrieve the initial `query` value from the property and store it in `state` as it may mutate.

Then, in the `onChange` function for the `input` element, retrieve the new value from the event argument and store it in `state` using `setState`. From there, you can call `setState` so that the `render` will be called. From the `doSearch` function, you can call the `onSearch` method which in this example, calls a function declared in `App`.

[Here's](http://jsbin.com/baweda/3/edit?html,js,output) a complete example.

```
var SearchBox = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
      onSearch: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired   
    },

    // grab the query value and put it into state
    // as the value may mutate as the user types
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        query: this.props.query || ''
      };    
    },

    // if a change is ever propogated through properties
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
      this.setState({ query: nextProps.query || '' });
    },

    doSearch:function(event){        
        // grab the new value from the input text box
        var newQuery = event.target.value || '';
        this.setState({ query: newQuery });

        this.props.onSearch.call(this, newQuery);
    },
    render:function(){
        return (<input type="text" 
            placeholder="Search Name" 
            value={ this.state.query } 
            onChange={ this.doSearch }/>);
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({          
  _onSearch: function(query) {
    console.log(query);
  },  
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBox onSearch={ this._onSearch } />
      </div>);

  }
});

React.render(<App />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `onKeyUp={this.doSearch}` instead of `onChange={this.doSearch}`. I hope this will work.